# Starting SQLPlus in linux

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

How do you start sqlplus in linux? I know this is a service in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it seems its this easy:

```
isqlplusctl start'
```

This requires the environment to be setup properly, which is often done in the login scripts of the oracle user:

```
 isqlplusctl stop
 ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.1.0/db_1
 ORACLE_SID=test
 export ORACLE_HOME ORACLE_SID
 isqlplusctl start
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need console version of sqlplus, then: 

1) Install appropriate version of Oracle client downloaded from oracle.com
2) Add this strings to your .bashrc (if shell is bash) in home folder

```
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/11  #Change this if other
export ORACLE_HOME

TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
export TNS_ADMIN

ORACLE_BASE=/opt/oracle
export ORACLE_BASE

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

3) Run

```
$ sqlplus /nolog
SQL> connect sys@DBNAME as sysdba
```